# Understanding activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am just starting my experience with Android development (I am watching tutorials right now). I looked at the activity lifecycle on the Android developers page, and I realized that the activity always goes through the `onResume()` method before it's visible to the user. Assuming I will be using no fragments in the activity, does that mean that most of the code logic should be within the `onResume()` method, and I should just inflate the layout once inside the `onCreate()` at the beginning?

Comment: It really depends on what you expect from the activity. Do you have work that needs to be done everytime the activity is shown? Or just once at the creation of the activity?

Comment: one-time initialization goes in onCreate, some times initialization of stuff can go in onResume depending on what you need as Luca said. Most of the code is usually in event listeners such as onClick for the UI click events. onResume is usually reserved for registering listeners and callbacks, unless you're doing something special. There will be many cases where you have an activity that does not override onResume simply because there is no need

Comment: initialization of **resources and variables** should be done in **onCreate()**. because, when the Activity goes into **onPause() or onStop()** the **onResume()** will be call and the same **variables and resource** will be initialized and **memory will be wasted**. If your logic to run **every time** when the activity goes into background and come back to foreground, based on priority write the logic in **onStart() and onResume()**.

Comment: Thanks guys I understood it better now. Just a beginner's misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer the site for the better understanding of the activity lifecycle 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
and also this for brief understanding 
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity

Now answering your question **onCreate()** is not just for inflating the layout.
The main part of the core logic is written here and **onResume()** is called when you minimize the or open the app once again it is called again and again but onCreate() is called once untill and unless the control is not forwarded to another activity

Like in Java the start running from 
public static void main(String[] args){
}

In Android(Activity) the first line will be executed will be from onCreate() and not from the onResume()

if you will practice the same and will habitual of this process again and again then you better understand what i m trying to tell nothing can be more useful than you practice and your understanding try to print the toast or Log on each and every state of the activity lifecycle and you better understand this without the help of anyone

Cheers Happy Coding!